# Array not populating in subscribe() in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

```
onButtonClick() {
this.http.get('ip:port/abc')
.subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
  [].push.apply(this.dummy, res);
  console.log(this.dummy);
});
}
```

when I check the console, the res object is being printed as below:

```
{lat: 29, lon: 82, label: "A", draggable: true}
```

But when I populate thee dummy array with the res object, it is not getting populated. Printing it on the console shows an array with zero length.

Comment: If `this.dummy` is an array, do this: `this.dummy.push(res)`

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this :

```
dummy : any = [];
onButtonClick() {
     this.http.get('ip:port/abc')
     .subscribe(res => {
     console.log(res);
     this.dummy.push(res);
     console.log(this.dummy);
  });
}
```

Comment: You literally told him to do the same thing I told him to do, 4 hours later... -_-

Comment: Oh, I actually didn't look at the comments. 